# How to invoke a java function when some data is added to an arraylist

Tags: java, function, class, arraylist, invoke

Assuming I have an ArrayList in ClassA and a method named `send` in ClassB,
how can I invoke `send` whenever something is added to the ArrayList in ClassA?

Comment: You could setup a listener in `ClassA` which would update `ClassB` whenever the data changes.  Can you share some code with us?

Comment: how exactly do you want the method to be invoked? Do you want it to be called automatically based on an `event` when data in the ArrayList changes or do you want to modify `a` and call the function yourself?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How to make a listener from one class to another, do you have any reference ?

Answer (score 1):

You should extend `ArrayList` and override the `add` method to call a listener:

```
 class MyArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private MyArrayListListener<T> listener;

    public void setListener(MyArrayListListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        if(listener != null) {
            listener.elementAdded(t);
        }
        return super.add(t);
    }
}

interface MyArrayListListener<T> {
    void elementAdded(T element);
}
```

And use it like this:

```
MyArrayList<String> list = new MyArrayList<>();
list.setListener(new MyArrayListListener<String>() {
      @Override
      public void elementAdded(String element) {
            // do whatever you want
      }
 });
 list.add("elementAdded gets called now");
```

Comment: For consistency, I would also overwrite `addAll`

Comment: For good design, I wouldn't extend `ArrayList`, but prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

For most use cases, it is the best idea to define a custom class with and `add` method which holds a `List` as a field. Then you can do your custom logic whenever the `add` of your class is called.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a wrapper class for `List`, so you could do something like

```
ListenableList<String> list = new ListenableList<>(new ArrayList<>());
list.addListener(...);

public class ListenableList<T> implements List<T> {
    private List<T> list;
    public ListenableList(List<T> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void add(T element) {
        list.add(element);
        invokeAddEvent();
    }
    // etc.
```

`ListenableList` would implement `List` and delegate all the methods to the underlying list (`ArrayList` in the example), as well as generate events. This would allow you to have different events for adding, removing and even getting elements.

It's a basic [proxy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).